# extraer elemento a arraylist y pasarlo a string

Tags: java, android

Como sabrán para extraer un elento de un ArrayList se hace de la siguiente forma;

```
arraylist.get(position).get("elemento")
```

para convertirlo a String según leí:

```
String abc =TextUtils.join("", ArrayList);
```

Como hacer para sacar un elemento en concreto y convertirlo a String? ejemplo:

```
 String abc =TextUtils.join("", ArrayList.get(position).get(elemento));
```

intente de esa forma pero no funciona.

Comment: Al parecer tienes un `List<Map<String, Object>>` o similar. Este tipo de información es útil para poder comprender bien tu caso puntual y dar una respuesta acertada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para pasar un Elemento de un ArrayList a String solo debes hacer lo siguiente

```
String cadena = tuLista.get(indice).toString();
```

Añade mas informacion sobre que objetos tiene tu lista para orientarte mejor, Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias...................................................................................... String estadoo = userlist.get(position).get("estado").toString(); funcionó perfecto.

Comment: Me parece que el `toString` no es necesario, a no ser que sea un array de Objetos. Esto sólo funcionaría: **`String estadoo = userlist.get(position).get("estado");`**

Answer (score 0):

Depende de cómo sea tu `ArrayList`:

- Si está constituido por objetos del tipo `String` o por objetos que envuelven datos primitivos:  `Integer`, `Long`,  etc, no necesitas usar `toString` para mostrarlos. Puedes mostrarlos como mostrarías cualquier variable de su tipo. Eso significa que lo podrás leer usando el método `get(indice)`
- Si está constituido por objetos, entonces puedes leerlo agregando al método `get(indice)` el método `toString()` o un método parcial, en caso de  querer obtener un dato específico del array, por ejemplo `getName()` en el caso de la clase `People`.

Hay que tener en cuenta que el primer elemento tiene siempre el índice `0` y así sucesivamente.

Veamos un ejemplo con código:

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/XZBN31697)**</kbd>

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    
        ArrayList<Integer> arrListInt = new ArrayList<Integer>(3);
        ArrayList<String> arrListString = new ArrayList<String>(3);
        ArrayList<People> arrListPeople = new ArrayList<People>(3);


        arrListInt.add(15);
        arrListInt.add(22);
        arrListInt.add(33);

        arrListString.add("Uno");
        arrListString.add("Dos");
        arrListString.add("Tres");
        
        arrListPeople.add(new People("Pedro",28));
        arrListPeople.add(new People("Santiago",30));
        arrListPeople.add(new People("Juan",22));

        System.out.println("Primer elemento de arrListInt: " + arrListInt.get(0));      
        System.out.println("Segundo elemento de arrListString: = " + arrListString.get(1));      

        System.out.println("Tercera Persona de arrListPeople: = " + arrListPeople.get(2).toString());      
        System.out.println("Segunda Persona (Nombre) de arrListPeople: = " + arrListPeople.get(1).getName());      
        
   }
      
    
}


class People 
{
    String name;
    int age;

    People (String name,int age) 
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }

    String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }

    int getAge() 
    {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "Nombre: "+getName()+" - Edad:"+getAge();
      }

}
```

---

### `Resultado:`

```
Primer elemento de arrListInt: 15
Segundo elemento de arrListString: = Dos
Tercera Persona de arrListPeople: = Nombre: Juan - Edad:22
Segunda Persona (Nombre) de arrListPeople: = Santiago
```

Comment: *Si está constituido por tipos primitivos* un `ArrayList` nunca puede estar constituido por tipos primitivos. Si agregas un primitivo a un `ArrayList`, Java hará el boxing al wrapper correspondiente, de manera que `toString` funcionará.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ dije: _**no necesitas** usar toString_. no dije que no funcionaría. ¿Para qué usar un método suplementario, si lo puedes hacer sólo con el `get`?Tu comentario parece una apología del `toString` que puede confundir al OP.

Comment: Mi punto es la parte de **primitivos en un `ArrayList`**, eso es **imposible**.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ cuando ves el `add`  lo que se agregan son primitivos, a eso me refería. Luego edito la respuesta para no dar lugar a confusiones.

Comment: Sí, puedes tener la sensación de "agregar primitivos" pero en realidad se aplica el autoboxing. Este tipo de explicaciones a medio camino confunden a la gente.

Answer (score -1):

**Muy sencillo**

Me doy por entendido que es un array bidimensional

```
    String elemento= nombreDelarray.get(positionPadre).get(positionHijo).toString();
```

Comment: Cuidado, no es un arreglo bidimensional. Parece que es algo del estilo `List<Map<String, Object>>`. Esto porque `arraylist.get(position)` sigue un patrón similar al de [`List#get(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) y el siguiente método `.get("elemento")` sigue un patrón similar al de `[Map#get(Object key)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-). Además, un arreglo bidimensional se podría acceder como `arreglo[x][y]`.